# передача строки в split() с экранированием её части

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть необходимость работать именно с питоном 3.5, посему форматирую строку с параметрами и дальше мне нужно её разбить на части

```
name1 = Alex
name2 = Jhon
string = "First user name is {} and second user name is {}".format(name1, name2)
string.split()
```

всё хорошо пока name1 и name2 состоят из одного слова, когда это не так эти слова тоже разбиваются, а мне нужно их экранировать от этого. Разделитель именно пробел, т.е. string.split() остаётся как был.
В итоге если name1 = Alex Smith, то он и должен как 1 объект оставаться после сплита:

... 'name' 'is' 'Alex Smith' ...

Comment: а строка `string` у вас всегда одинаковая?

Comment: да, одна и та же, только аргумент может быть из нескольких слов, изначально не известно сколько их будет

Comment: ну так а зачем вы собираете ее фртматом? придумали себе проблему. Делайте проще: `string = "First user name is "+name1+" and second user name is " + name2`

Comment: а что это изменит? split пройдётся и по этому точно так же, разве нет?

Comment: я пробовал такую штуку:
    string = "First user name is {!r} and second user name is {!r}".format(name1, name2)
на печать выходят так же разные части но уже дополнительно экранированные "" вокруг, надо как то чтобы split не проходился по тому что внутри ""

Comment: Вы не поняли. Зачем вы вообще сначала собираете строку, а затем сплитите ее?  смысл в чем? если сразу можно написать "name is " + name1

Comment: смысл в том что то что я написал это абстракция, в реальной задаче каждое слово это команда, которая передаётся дальше, и вот эта строка это набор таких команд, и внутри этой строки есть пути к файлам, так вот проблема в том что изначально эти пути предполагались в виде: /folder1/folder2/.../folderK/folderN/file.txt, а теперь оказывается что сами папки по пути могут быть с названиями 'hello world' и вот этот пробел делает проблему при сплите

Comment: Если пути содержат пробелы, то вы в любом случае никак не определите, что это не разные команды, а часть одного пути. Для примера, при передаче параметров командной строки пути с пробелами нужно оборачивать в кавычки или экранировать пробелы (`\ `). Либо должен быть фиксированный формат: одно слово - команда, все что после него - один параметр, тогда нужно делить по первому пробелу.

Comment: В целом лучше задавать вопрос с максимально приближенными к реальной ситуации данными (пример с путями в данном случае), вместо бессмысленных абстрактных примеров.

Comment: почему бы вам не использовать любой другой символ для разделения, которого не может быть в команде и не может быть в путях

Comment: #insolor: спасибо, т.е. нужно перерабатывать алгоритм, правильно понимаю?

#n1tr0xs: допустим я возьму символ '_', ну а если пользователь создаст папку: folder_1? застраховаться тут нельзя по идее, все другие символы придётся отметать.

Comment: @ILikeTea я еще раз повторю *которого не может быть в команде и не может быть в путях*. `:` к примеру

Comment: дело в том что всё может быть, пути от ОС зависят, допустим в винде будет С:/...
не, я вроди придумал как сделать, нужно разбить строку на части, сплитануть их и потом туда добавить пути в нужное место, т.к. как insolor сказал что не выйдет так схитрить :)

Comment: `?` насколько я знаю, даже линукс не пропустит в путь. есть еще знаки `<>|*`

Comment: да и к тому же, если ваша строка всегда одинакова, то вы можете сначала `split`, а потом вставить пользовательский ввод на нужное место в списке (как вы сами и написали)

Comment: именно так и поступлю, схитрить перед сплитом не получится, а так хотелось)) ладно спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил использовать временный разделитель:

```
name1 = 'Alex Black'
name2 = 'Jhon'
tempDelimiter = '#56'

string = "First user name is {} and second user name is {}"
string = string.replace(' ', tempDelimiter).format(name1, name2)

result = string.split(tempDelimiter)
print(result)
```

> ['First', 'user', 'name', 'is', 'Alex Black', 'and', 'second', 'user', 'name', 'is', 'Jhon']

`tempDelimiter` можно и другой записать, в зависимости от содержимого строки.

Думаю, этот способ проще, чем вставка в итоговый список.